# Why require(lodash) retrieve an out-of-date version?

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash, termux

I have installed node on my Android phone via Termux and have recently upgraded lodash globally to v4

```
$ npm -v
5.6.0

$ node -v
v8.9.2

$ npm i -g lodash
+ lodash@4.17.4

$ head -1 $NODE_PATH/lodash/README.md
# lodash v4.17.4
```

However when I require it, node gives me version 3.

```
$ node 
> require('lodash')
  ...
  VERSION: '3.10.1'
```

I don't have a node_modules folder where I did that require. Does any one know why this strange behavior occurs and how to fix it? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following locations :

> Additionally, Node.js will search in the following locations:
>
> 1. $HOME/.node_modules
> 2. $HOME/.node_libraries
> 3. $PREFIX/lib/node

source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: Also make sure you don't have a `node_module` folder in parent directory up to root. [source](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

Comment: That's exactly where I found lodash v3. In the parent folder. lol